# This is an error in flutter kindly give me solution

Tags: gradle, assets

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: images/thh.jpg.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1